# How to kill Janissaries

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

Is there an efficient way to tackle these guys? I've tried quite a few things and have resorted to running away and hitting them with throwing knives or bombs.

I can't seem to find the tutorial on how to beat them.

http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Janissaries

Comment: It's been a while, but I think they are receptive to counter attacks.

Comment: @kotekzot I found the opposite! They seem to block or parry everything :*(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of different ways:

1. Switch to unarmed, counter-steal, and then attack them.
2. Dodge then attack while unarmed.
3. Dodge then attack with a fast weapon, like your dagger.
4. Poison dart them and hten get out of the way before they start flailing.
5. Let them draw a bead on you with their gun and then call in a recruit to backstab them.
6. Bomb them from a distance before you get into melee range

Comment: Because they are Janissaries, they normally counter your counter-steal, however I often find that if you just play the offensive and wait for them to attack, you can take then down with counters from daggers, because of the speed of your weapon compared to the speed of the Janissaries

Comment: Unarmed, dodge then attack worked a treat!

Answer (score 1):

I tended to do one of a few things:

- Using the hidden blade, counter their attacks.  Although this isn't a one-hit kill, it does damage them, and if you can consistently get the timing down, after a few counters they'll go down.
- Toss poison bombs (or other lethal bombs) at them.  If you're far enough in the game, you've probably got plenty of materials, and you can craft more bombs from the weapon selection screen.  It's not infinite, but usually you've got enough in reserve to handle as many as you're likely to encounter on a given mission.
- Certain non-lethal bombs will make them vulnerable to one-hit kills.  I seem to recall smoke and caltrop bombs both working for this.
- Call for backup.  Although it's a bit risky, and you might occasionally lose an assassin to them, calling in your assassins to distract or murder them tends to be a quick way to resolve combat.

Comment: Smoke bombs will also allow you to kill them in one shot, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Fluttershy, I couldn't remember if this was right or not, but I seem to remember there being a bomb tutorial about this feature.

Comment: @agent86 it is. Anyone hit with a smoke bomb, caltrop or other bomb with the same effect can be assassinated without risk of failure, because they cant see / are holding their feet / ect

Comment: If it's a bomb tutorial it would certainly explain why I couldn't find it in the enemies section! Will try tonight! Accepted on good faith ;)

Answer (score 0):

I get the mercenaries to help me. I counter attacks, and hit and kick at every chance I get; I also shoot and throw knifes and bombs a lot.

Before you do **anything** make sure everything is repaired and you have full medicine and ammunition. I killed 2 and also a few other guards and got 2 chests. You probably know what place Imm taking about, near mercenary hire, tailor and a view point to the left side of the Galata District. Good luck!